# PHP error suppression or isset

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of more than 50 indefinite keys means i am not sure one particular field will be there or not.
I have two option to assign array values to other.

**First**

```
 $array2['someOtheField'] = isset($array1['somefield'])?$array1['somefield']:null;
```

**Second**

```
 $array2['someOtherField'] = @ $array1['somefield'];
```

Can anyone please suggest ,Which one is better for my case.
Or, is there any way i can suppress errors for one block of code .

Comment: Read the manual page about  [`@`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) and I'm sure you definitely get the answer

Comment: [`// Turn off all error reporting 
error_reporting(0);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Now thats the first time I have seen you suggest turning error reporting OFF Ralph, have you checked your temperature, maybe you are a bit feverish @Fred-ii-

Comment: @RiggsFolly *There's a first time for everything Smokey* ;-) *Feelin' hot hot hot* ♫

Comment: Use `isset`, seriously, `@` has a severe impact on performance and is bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you need this code to be really fast, then the second option is better due to my experience from profiling PHP code.

If it is really going to be only 50 elements, I would use the first option, because it's clear what kind of problem you are trying to avoid.

Comment: Actually, it is slower to use the suppression operator. http://seanmonstar.com/post/909029460/php-error-suppression-performance

Comment: [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: Thanks man! I believe more votes go to isset . So going with isset.

Comment: @anwerjunaid Glad to help. `isset` is generally a better choice. As I said in the answer it was my experience with particular version of PHP where `@` was the faster solution. But as others said, even that is questionable.

Answer (score 1):

The good approach is ALWAYS check the variable before you use it. So the first variant is better.Also I would offer to think about the value by default:

```
 $array2['someOtheField'] = isset($array1['somefield'])?$array1['somefield']:null;
```

If this is array of strings so :null should be changed to :"", in array of integers so :0;
This will bring more consistency in your code.

By the way, the idea of turning off the alerts is not good. Just imagine situation that you need to debug something. You will put the alerts on and the page will full of not relevant alerts that you will be force to fix before you find YOUR relevant alert of your bug